# Preventing Excel from updating the screen in C#

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

I am writing an add-in in VIsual C# for Excel 2010. This add-in retrieves some data from a we service and writes the results into cells of a certain spreadsheet. However I don't want Excel to display filling the cells with values as this takes a lot of time. So I tried the following piece of code:

```
ExcelApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
GetFolderTreeRecursive(FolderTree);
ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = true;
```

`GetFolderTreeRecursive` basically handles the web service call and writes response values to Excel cells like this:

`Globals.TestCases.Cells[FolderTreeRowIndex, FolderTreeColumnIndex].Value2 = CurrentFolder.recordid;`

Unfortunately Excel still displays all of the cells being written. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just referenced the wrong Excel application object. Using the following statement returns the current Excel application and not a new one as I have implemented accidentially.

`ExcelApp = Globals.ThisWorkbook.ThisApplication;`